# Pandas : Saving indivisual file which is having same column name in two dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I wanted cancat Two dataframe which share same  column name  and save as indivisual file having same column name and save file as column name

my dataframe looking like

```
A1=
 name   exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
 arun    0     12    25     0
 joy     20     1    0      26
 jeev    30    0     0       25

B2=
 name   exam1 exam2 exam3 exam4
 arun    20     26    0     0
 joy     30     0    25     3
 jeev    17     2    15    25
```

what I wanted as a output
save diffrent file with column name such as exam1.txt, exam2.txt, exam3.txt etc  i have very big dataframe
output indivisual file look like
example: exam1.txt

```
name  exam1_A1   exam1_B1
 arun     0          20
 joy      20         30
 jeev     30         17
```

I try to use cancat two dataframe pd.concat([A1,B1], axis=0) but not able get what I wanted. can any one suggest me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loop with `merge`:

```
for col in A1.columns[1:]:

    (A1[['namme',col]]
       .merge(B1[['name',col]], on='name', suffixes=('_A1','_B1'))
       .to_csv(f'{col}.txt')
    )
```